# Splitting a string with java not working

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string in java that looks something like:

```
holdingco^(218) 333-4444^scott@holdingco.com
```

I set a string variable equal to it:

```
String value = "holdingco^(218) 333-4444^scott@holdingco.com";
```

Then I want to split this string into it's components:

```
String[] components = value.split("^");
```

However it does not split up the string.  I have tried escaping the carrot delimiter to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
String[] components = value.split("\\^");
```

The unescaped `^` means beginning of a string in a regex, and the unescaped `$` means end. You have to use two backslashes for escaping, as the string literal `"\\"` represents a single backslash, and that's what regex needs.

If you tried escaping with one backslash, it didn't compile, as `\^` is not a valid escape sequence in Java.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked!  I cannot accept your answer however for another 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

try with: `value.split("\\^");` this should work a bit better